# What is the notation for bounding running time in worst case with concrete example resulting in that worst case running time

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

I know that Big O is used to bound worst case running time. So an algorithm with running time $O(n^5)$ means its running time in worse case is less than $n^5$ asymptotically.

Similarly, one can say that for example merge sort's running time is $O(n^2)$  which is correct. But we know that there is a better bound for it: $O(n\log n)$. Technically speaking, one can say that every polytime algorithm has running time $O(2^n)$. This is correct, but not useful.

So my question is: what is the notation used for the case of worst case running time such that there exists an input in which the worst case running time happens.

In the merge sort example, one cannot construct an input example so that merge sort would take $n^2$ comparisons, but one can construct an example that requires the number of comparisons being about $n\log n$.

Comment: "I know that Big O is used to bound worst case running time." -- while not wrong, it's not the whole truth. I recommend you check out our [reference questions on asymptotics](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions/846#846); I think all the answers you need are there.

Comment: The use of the $\Theta$-notation for "overall complexity",
i.e. considering all computation over all inputs of a given size $n$, may
be *meaningless*. But it is always meaningful for worst case and best
case complexity. See my answer.

Comment: @Raphael I should have used the reference questions to answer. But I am used to the Landau page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See ["big 0" or Landau notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) in wikipedia. What you are looking
for is the section on [Bachmann-Landau notations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations).

- $f(n)\in O(g(n))$ means $f$ is bounded above by $g$ up to a constant.
- $f(n)\in \Omega(g(n))$ means $f$ is bounded below by $g$ up to a constant.
- $f(n)\in \Theta(g(n))$ means $f(n)\in O(g(n)) \wedge f(n)\in \Omega(g(n))$

**Further remarks**
(since the scope of the question is being implicitely extended)

These definitions can be used for worst case as well for a best case
analysis of complexity, starting from an analysis of respectively the
greatest or least costs over all inputs of size $n$.

Then, for algorithm $A$, let $A_{min}(n)$ and $A_{max}(n)$ be
respectively the best case and worst case complexity of $A$.

Then, omitting intentionally "worst case" or "best case". so as to
cover all cases, you can say that:

- the complexity of $A$ is $O(g(n)$ iff $A_{max}(n)\in O(g(n)$
- the complexity of $A$ is $\Omega(g(n)$ iff $A_{min}(n)\in \Omega(g(n)$

Now using the $\Theta$-notation is not necessarily meaningful for this
"overall" complexity of $A$. It is meaningful iff $O(A_{max}(n))=O(A_{min}(n))$

To be complete, many people also use average case analysis.

Also, people often mean worst case when they omit qualification of the complexity.

Comment: I think the OP understands the Landau notation.

Comment: @john_leo Then I do not understand what he is asking. Big O is for upperbounds. He refers to it explicitly, but is looking for lower bounds ... and does not mention Big $\Omega$.

Comment: I think he's asking for the term you use when you have a concrete example that needs the precise upper bound you claim.

Comment: @john_leo thank you. I want to know the notation used when there is an example that make the bound happens. I believe $\Theta$ is what I am after, but I have seen confusing comments so I want to ask for advice from the experts.

Comment: @randomA FrankW's answer is a lot better than what I would have said, so go with his.

Comment: @randomA So you are looking for *sharp* bounds. $\Omega$ and therewith $\Theta$ is indeed the answer.

Comment: @Raphael $\Omega$ alone is not sharper than $O$ alone.

Comment: @FrankW I was writing with the premise that $O$ is known, yes.

Comment: Is there a reason you used the number 0 instead of the letter O at the beginning?

Comment: @Buge There are actually 2 reasons. The first is that I am a poor
typist. The second is that in editing mode the "O" and the "0" are
very similar, as the central dot of the "0" hardly shows. The third is
that when I read a text (not necessarily mine), I often read what
should be written (I may of course be wrong about that) rather than
what is actually written. So I do not see typos. Sorry and thanks for
telling me. I will correct it for the next update, if it comes (there
are limitations on updates).

Answer (score 6):

In words, such a bound is called a *tight* bound. In the specific case of Landau notation, $\Theta$ can be used to indicate a tight bound.
You have to be somewhat careful about your wording, though:

- "The runtime of quicksort is in $O(n^2)$," is a correct statement (but somewhat imprecise).
- "The runtime of quicksort is in $O(n^2)$, and this bound is tight," is correct and expresses, what you want to express.
- "The worst-case runtime of quicksort is in $\Theta(n^2)$," is equivalent to the previous statement.
- But "The runtime of quicksort is in $\Theta(n^2)$," is not correct, since this statement implies that quicksort takes quadratic time on every input.

Comment: Ok, this is really a wording problem now. It has been a habit at school that when one talks about runtime, we implicitly refer to worst case runtime unless specified otherwise.

Comment: What is an *instance of quicksort* ? [cc @randomA ]

Comment: Being word by word correct, from your last point, worst case running time for bubble sort is $\Theta(n^2)$ would be a correct statement. Correct?

Comment: @babou I would implicitly understand it as an *input instance* for quicksort

Comment: @randomA An *input instance* of what size ?  :)

Comment: @babou implicitly of size $n$ sir :)

Comment: @randomA Yes, that statemant about bubble sort is correct.

Comment: @babou Is the new wording easier to understand?

Comment: @randomA My point is: an instance has a fixed size. We are talking of asymptotic behavior. So, if we are to be picky with English, let's be picky to the end.

Comment: I do understand what you are trying to say. But I believe it is more
easily said in English than formally, though I am sure we can both
manage it. Indeed you do need to quantify over all input of a given
size in the definition of the asymptotics.
 $\;\;\exists k>0\;\exists n_0\;\forall n>n_0\;\forall input\;\;size(input)=n
 \implies cost(sort(input))> k n^2\;\;$
But this is no longer in the realm of Landau notation, and was not in
the question. [cc @randomA ]

Comment: @babou The $\forall input$ takes that out of my question. It would still be applicable if my question is about best case lower bound. ie best case $\Omega$

Comment: @randomA I do agree that it is out of your question. *I thought I had answered your question.* But since the discussion was getting further, I followed, especially since everyone seemed to want more, and I was trying to be precise about it (see my updated answer, where it is much better expressed). I was wondering what you might find missing in my answer, as you were originally simply asking for notation, and I was sticking to that.

Answer (score 2):

Use the notation that expresses the strongest property you know to be true.

Suppose you have an algorithm.

- If you have a class of inputs on which the algorithm runs in time $O(f(n))$, this actually tells you nothing about the worst-case running time: the worst case is worse than something that's better than $f(n)$, which could be literally anything.
- If you have a class of inputs on which the algorithm runs in time $\Omega(f(n))$ or $\Theta(f(n))$, then you know that the worst case running time is at least as bad as this class, so the worst case is $\Omega(f(n))$.
- If you have a class of inputs which you know to be the worst case, and the algorithm runs in time $O(f(n))$, $\Omega(f(n))$ or $\Theta(f(n))$, they you know that the worst-case running time is $O(f(n))$, $\Omega(f(n))$ or $\Theta(f(n))$, respectively.

> In the merge sort example, one cannot construct an input example so that merge sort would take $n^2$ comparisons, but one can construct an example that requires the number of comparisons being about $n\log n$.

This falls into the third bullet: you have a class of inputs which you know to be the worst case, and the algorithm takes time $\Theta(n\log n)$ on those inputs. So the worst-case running time is exactly that: $\Theta(n\log n)$.

Comment: "Use the notation that expresses the strongest property you know to be true." -- And *never* make this an implicit assumption/convention.